# Associated primes of the symbolic power and ordinary power

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am struggling to understand the following quote from a paper of Arsie and Vatne "A note on symbolic powers and ordinary powers of homogeneous ideals":

> Our interest in the symbolic power stems from the fact that taking the
>   symbolic power of a homogeneous ideal gives the saturated ideal for a
>   scheme which is the scheme defined by the ordinary power, having
>   subtracted the embedded components. Thus, in some special cases, via
>   the symbolic power we can obtain the saturation of the ordinary power.

If $R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring, then the $m$th symbolic power is defined to be $I^{(m)} = R \cap \left(\bigcap_{P \in \text{Min}_R (R/I)} I^mR_P \right) \subseteq R_{(0)}$.

I interpret "having subtracted the embedded components" to mean that the embedded primes of $I^m$ do not contain $I^{(m)}$.

1. Is this interpretation correct and why is it true that the embedded primes of $I^m$ do not contain $I^{(m)}$? I am sure it is obvious from the definition so forgive me.
2. Are the only associated primes of $I^{(m)}$ the minimal primes of $I^m$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It suffices to consider when $I$ is a prime ideal. More concretely, let $R = k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ and $I = (x,z)$. Then $I^{(2)} = R \cap I^2R_I$. The primary decomposition of $I^2 = I^{(2)} \cap Q$ where $\sqrt{Q} = m =  (x,y,z)R$. Hence $Q$ is the embedded component. 
   When they say an embedded components (not embedded prime), I believe that they refer to $Q$ not $m$. Of course, $Q$ cannot contain $I^{(2)}$ when you have a "irredundant" primary decomposition. However, since an embedded component always contains a minimal component. Hence its radical contains the symbolic power.
2. This is true: if $I \subseteq p$ is minimal, then $\sqrt{IR_p} = pR_p$. Hence $IR_p$ is $pR_p$-primary. A contraction of a primary ideal is primary. Therefore, the intersection on the RHS of $I^{(m)}$ is a primary decomposition of $I^{(m)}$. This gives the set of associate primes of $I^{(m)}$.

As far as I understand the definition of symbolic powers of non-primary ideal is not universal. By the way, I do not understand what you mean by $R_{(0)}$.

Comment: I meant to write commutative Noetherian domain rather than ring. So $R_{(0)}$ is the fraction field. Thanks for your answer.